# selectbox option list change detection on other selectbox change not detecting the change

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have two selectbox, primary and secondary. If user changes the value in primarybox, it refetches the API and get new data for secondary selectbox. Problem is I want to trigger customEvent secondary selectbox when primary changes. 
Below is the sample code I am using

```
//--------------

var secondary = document.querySelector('#secondary');
var primary = document.querySelector('#primary');

/** I want to fire customEvent for primary and secondary both by passing event */
primary.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    this.$emit('customEvent', e);
//logic to chnage the list for secondary 
    console.log('primary',e);
});
secondary.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    this.$emit('customEvent', e); //Not working when i am priggering change in primary
});
```

Comment: It's not very clear from your question what exactly you are trying to do.
you are trying to trigger 'customEvent' when primary changes, but you want it to get the secondary? or you want to trigger the event from secondary?

Comment: I want to trigger the event for secondary as well. basically it is because data has been changed secondary selectbox also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to trigger the change event for the secondary once you have loaded the list.
Something like below:

```js
var secondary = document.querySelector('#secondary');
var primary = document.querySelector('#primary');

primary.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    this.$emit('customEvent', e);
//logic to chnage the list for secondary 
    //trigger change event on secondary after loading data
    secondary.$emit('change');
    console.log('primary change triggered',e);
});
secondary.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    this.$emit('customEvent', e); 
    console.log('secondary change triggered',e);
});
```